# Descargar y mostrar imágenes en intervalos desde un txt

Tags: python, imagen, cv2

Buen día:
Estoy tratando de realizar un programa que baje unas imágenes por medio de unos url escritos en un .txt y luego las muestre en una ventana con intervalos de dos segundos cada una.
En conclusión el programa debe:
-Leer el .txt (dónde están los urls)
-Acceder al url
-Descargar la imagen.
-Y por último mostrar cada una en una ventana con intervalos de 2s.

```
import requests
url = 'http://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire3/cbb55a6382682bf71e91f685c6473c5a1487736090_full.jpg'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('imag1.jpg', 'wb').write(r.content)

import requests
url = 'https://dw9to29mmj727.cloudfront.net/promo/2016/5252-SeriesHeaders_HxH_2000x800.jpg'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('imag2.jpg', 'wb').write(r.content)

import requests
url = 'https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--jm2bRouE--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/pmsqi3ecbbgqpqsetmgr.png'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('imag3.jpg', 'wb').write(r.content)



#display_imag1_2segundos
imgn = cv2.imread('imag1.jpg')
cv2.imshow('imagen_2s',imgn)  
cv2.waitKey(2000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


#display_imag2_2segundos
imgn = cv2.imread('imag2.jpg')
cv2.imshow('imagen_2s',imgn)  
cv2.waitKey(2000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#display_imag3_2segundos
imgn = cv2.imread('imag3.jpg')
cv2.imshow('imagen_2s',imgn)  
cv2.waitKey(2000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hasta ahorita he descargado una por una (manualmente) pero necesito crear un loop para descargarlas y mostrarlas ya que son 15 imágenes y el fragmento de código al final lo estoy usando para desplegar una por una pero también es de forma manual. No encuentro mucha información de cómo automatizar las dos tareas. Agradezco mucho si alguien por aquí tiene información que pueda ayudarme, compartirla conmigo.

Al final quedó así:

```
import requests
import cv2

abrir=open("mylinks.txt","r")
links=abrir.read()
abrir.close()
mislinks=links.splitlines()

for link in mislinks:
    r = requests.get(link, allow_redirects=True)
    open("temporal.jpg",'wb').write(r.content)   
    cv2.waitKey(100)

    imgn = cv2.imread('temporal.jpg')
    cv2.imshow('imagen_2s',imgn)  
    cv2.waitKey(2000)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las dos partes (descargar imágenes y mostrarlas cada dos segundos) ya las tienes, que es lo más complicado. Solo te faltaba el bucle para no repetir tanto código.

Puesto que todas tus imágenes siguen el mismo patrón, `imag1.jpg`, `imag2.jpg`... te propongo que metas en un diccionario las urls con la clave igual a cada número para aprovecharlo a la hora de nombrar a los archivos. Este diccionario se puede crear leyendo directamente de tu txt, pero al no tener la estructura no te puedo indicar cómo. Te indico más abajo cómo crear ese diccionario con python suponiendo que en tu txt hay una `url` en cada linea.

Te pongo el código con las tres `urls` que has puesto, tendrías que incluir las demás:

```
import requests
import cv2

urls = {
    1: 'http://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire3/cbb55a6382682bf71e91f685c6473c5a1487736090_full.jpg',
    2: 'https://dw9to29mmj727.cloudfront.net/promo/2016/5252-SeriesHeaders_HxH_2000x800.jpg',
    3: 'https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--jm2bRouE--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/pmsqi3ecbbgqpqsetmgr.png'
}

# Parte para descargar las imágenes
for n, url in urls.items():
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    with open(f'imag{n}.jpg', 'wb') as img:
        img.write(r.content)

# Parte para mostrarlas cada 2 segundos
for n in range(1, 16):
    imgn = cv2.imread(f'imag{n}.jpg')
    cv2.imshow('imagen_2s', imgn)
    cv2.waitKey(2000)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

El primer bucle es para descargar las imágenes, por lo que una vez descargadas, no lo necesitarías. Al poner `for n, url in urls.items()` almacenarías en `n` las claves del diccionario (números) y en `url` los valores (urls).

El segundo bucle recorre los números de 1 a 15 con `for n in range(1, 16)` y al poner `f'imag{n}.jpg'` iría cambiando la `n` por cada uno de ellos en cada ciclo del bucle.

**Crear el diccionario con python**

Suponiendo que tu txt tiene únicamente una `url` por línea, sustituyendo el diccionario `urls` por este fragmento de código, te lo generará automáticamente:

```
urls = {}

with open('archivo.txt', 'r') as file:
    for n, url in enumerate(file, start=1):
        urls[n] = url.rstrip('\n')
```

Si no fuese el caso, te puede valer parta investigar un poco como hacerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Adrián en efecto tuve que hacer algo similar. Usé un bucle para crear un archivo temporal y un bloque que corriera las imágenes dentro del temporal por cada 2 segundos: Muy similar al prototipo que mencionas¡ muchas gracias por tu aportación y tu tiempo¡